# Using duplicates to create different text files

Tags: python, file, list, duplicates

I am struggling to create a text file from another text file.

My text file is:

```
0.0 99.13 0.11
0.5 19.67 0.59
0.5 22.23 1.22
1.0 9.67  0.08
```

and I would like to create a text file such as:

```
0.0 99.13 0.11
0.5 19.67 0.59
1.0 9.67  0.08
```

or

```
0.0 99.13 0.11
0.5 22.23 1.22
1.0 9.67  0.08
```

Generally, every time there would be a duplicate value in the first column of my file I would like to create a file with just one of the duplicates and a value of the chosen line.

My code so far is:

```
def createFile(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as fh:
        data = fh.read()
    for row in data.splitlines():
        column = row.split()
        print column 
>>> 
['0.0', '99.13', '0.11']
['0.5', '19.67', '0.59']
['0.5', '22.23', '1.22']
['1.0', '9.67', '0.08']
```

which would let my play with the indexes - maybe checking if column[0] is repeated and then printing the line? or would creating a dictionary be easier?

Cheers,
Kate

Comment: Can duplicated values be in non-consecutive lines?

Comment: Actually, the list is sorted, so the duplicates will always be in consecutive lines.

Comment: @kate88 okay that makes things a bit easier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If the duplicates are grouped in order**, use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = """0.0 99.13 0.11
0.5 19.67 0.59
0.5 22.23 1.22
1.0 9.67  0.08""".split('\n')

result = [list(j) for i, j in groupby(data, lambda x: x.split(' ', 1)[0])]

files_num = 0
for e in result:
    files_num = max(files_num, len(e))

for i in range(files_num):
    with open('{}.txt'.format(i), 'w+') as f:
        for line in result:
            min_index = min(i, len(line)-1)
            f.write('{}\n'.format(line[min_index]))
```

**0.txt:**

```
0.0 99.13 0.11
0.5 19.67 0.59
1.0 9.67  0.08
```

**1.txt:**

```
0.0 99.13 0.11
0.5 22.23 1.22
1.0 9.67  0.08
```

---

Otherwise, if they are not grouped in order, you can use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) this way (like [1_CR suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835231/using-duplicates-to-create-different-text-files/16837561#16837561), but with some changes):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = """0.0 99.13 0.11
0.5 19.67 0.59
1.0 9.67  0.08
0.5 22.23 1.22""".split('\n')

d = OrderedDict()
for line in data:
    split = line.split(' ', 1)
    d.setdefault(split[0], []).extend(split[1:])

print(d)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([ ('0.0', ['99.13 0.11']), 
              ('0.5', ['19.67 0.59', '22.23 1.22']), 
              ('1.0', ['9.67  0.08']) ])
```

Comment: I don't think that is what she's looking for

Comment: The OP never said the values were sorted, and this will fail if the lines are shuffled.

Comment: Well it suffers from 2 things one it's not creating a split into two files (your solution just drops the second line) and the values are not supposed to be sorted.

Comment: @AhmedMasud The OP said "to create a text file such as ... **or** ...", so giving only the first output seems okay. The important thing is to remove duplicates, not to produce every possible file without duplicates.

Comment: Thank you all for help! I actually would like to create both files. I said 'or', because due to different circumstances I would like to create version1 (taking the first line with 0.5) OR version2(taking the second line with 0.5). I am sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @segfolt I misunderstood kate's requirement I thought it was way more complex than it turned out to be (clarification made a big differnece) +1'd your solution ; I thought she wanted to make a new file one for EACH permutation

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from collections import OrderedDict
s = '''\
0.0 99.13 0.11
0.5 19.67 0.59
0.5 22.23 1.22
1.0 9.67  0.08
'''
f = StringIO(s)
d = OrderedDict()
for line in f:
    fields = line.split()
    d[fields[0]] = fields[1:]

for key in d:
    print key, ' '.join(d[key])

0.0 99.13 0.11
0.5 22.23 1.22
1.0 9.67 0.08
```